# CSS vertical align text with image

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a bar with text and images.
My problem is that the text is not vertically aligned with the images.
I tried in this way with no success.

```
<div class="bar">   
   <span class="strip">DOWNLOAD</span>
   <span class="divider"></span>
   <span class="strip">SUBMIT</span>
   <span class="divider"></span>
</div>
```

css

```
.bar {
   width: 100%;
   height: 20px;
   background: #c6d4db;
 }

.strip {
   display: inline-block;
   height: 20px;
   line-height: 20px;
   background: #c6d4db;
   font-family: 'OpenSans','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
   font-size: 10px;
 }

.divider {
   display: inline-block;
   height: 20px;
   line-height: 20px;
   width: 18px;
   background: url("http://cdn.imghack.se/images/9d5972b90a4390e90f99530d7915c07b.png") no-repeat center;
 }
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4NzD9/)

What would be the correct way to do it?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vertical-align:top;` is what you are looking for.

Here is a simpler way though :)

**First Example**

**Changed height to `20px`**

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/4NzD9/8/)

HTML

```
<div class="bar">   
    <a>DOWNLOAD</a>
    <a>SUBMIT</a>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .bar {
    background: #c6d4db;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.bar a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    background: #c6d4db url("http://cdn.imghack.se/images/9d5972b90a4390e90f99530d7915c07b.png") no-repeat right;
    font-family:'OpenSans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 5px;
}
```

**Here is another way with `:after` :)**

**Second Example**

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/4NzD9/6/)

HTML

```
<div class="bar">   
    <a>DOWNLOAD</a>
    <a>SUBMIT</a>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bar {
    background: #c6d4db;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.bar a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    background: #c6d4db;
    font-family:'OpenSans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.bar a:after {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    content:"";
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    background: url("http://cdn.imghack.se/images/9d5972b90a4390e90f99530d7915c07b.png") no-repeat center;
}
```

Comment: It's very clean but there is a problem in the bottom of arrow

Comment: Change the height to `20px;` for `.bar a` in my first example.

Comment: The last one : to finish the bar with the arrow, how I could do that? thanks

Comment: Look at this [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4NzD9/9/). If you make a second background image that has a white background and isn't opaque, you will get the affect you want. Know what I mean?

Comment: [Here is what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/4NzD9/10/) - Background is white. Easiest way to achieve what you want :)

Answer (score 2):

They are currently aligned by the baseline, where the bottom of the **text** will be vertically aligned with the bottom of the image. Vertically align your elements at the top instead:

```
.strip {
     display: inline-block;
     height: 20px;
     line-height: 20px;
     background: #c6d4db;
     font-family: 'OpenSans','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
     font-size: 10px;
     vertical-align:top;
}
.divider {
     display: inline-block;
     height: 20px;
     line-height: 20px;
     width: 18px;
     background: url("http://cdn.imghack.se/images/9d5972b90a4390e90f99530d7915c07b.png") no-repeat center;
     vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4NzD9/1/)

Comment: Or just use a CSS arrow instead of a non-semantic styling img div.

Comment: This is ok, but now I'm trying adding an icon font-awesome in this text, but even if the imposed vertical-align: top, does not work. how could I do? thanks